# Accessing Value of NSDictionary within array

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays

I appear to be having some difficulty accessing the value of a particular value within a Key/Value on a multidiamentional array

the array is structured as follows

```
itemsInSection  __NSCFDictionary *  1 key/value pair    0x00000001356b9e10
[0] struct __lldb_autogen_nspair        
key __NSCFString *  @"RequestTitle" 0x0000000135647350
value   __NSCFArray *   @"14 objects"   0x00000001356972c0
[0] __NSCFDictionary *  3 key/value pairs   0x000000013565cda0
[0] struct __lldb_autogen_nspair        
[1] struct __lldb_autogen_nspair        
key NSTaggedPointerString * @"path" 0xa000000687461704
value   __NSCFString *  @"upload/images/14439822460482106558105.jpg"    0x00000001356b9ef0
[2] struct __lldb_autogen_nspair        
[1] __NSCFDictionary *  3 key/value pairs   0x00000001356bd960
[2] __NSCFDictionary *  3 key/value pairs   0x00000001356720a0
[3] __NSCFDictionary *  3 key/value pairs   0x000000013564ff80
[4] __NSCFDictionary *  3 key/value pairs   0x00000001356bc790
[5] __NSCFDictionary *  3 key/value pairs   0x00000001356bca80
[6] __NSCFDictionary *  3 key/value pairs   0x00000001356bdad0
[7] __NSCFDictionary *  3 key/value pairs   0x00000001356bc010
[8] __NSCFDictionary *  3 key/value pairs   0x00000001356bdc90
[9] __NSCFDictionary *  3 key/value pairs   0x00000001356bc9d0
[10]    __NSCFDictionary *  3 key/value pairs   0x00000001356bd580
[11]    __NSCFDictionary *  3 key/value pairs   0x00000001356bd140
[12]    __NSCFDictionary *  3 key/value pairs   0x00000001356bd8b0
[13]    __NSCFDictionary *  3 key/value pairs   0x00000001356bd360
```

The value that i am looking for is

```
value   __NSCFString *  @"upload/images/14439822460482106558105.jpg"
```

This code relates to a Collection View, so i need to iterate through all 14 objects within the array

The call need to go here

```
-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    PatternViewCellCollectionViewCell  *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"PatternCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    NSDictionary *itemsInSection  = [self.patternImagesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];


   // NSString *myPatternString = [itemsInSection][0][indexPath.row];



    cell.patternImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"angry_birds_cake.jpg"];
    cell.patternViewLabel.text = @"angry_birds_cake.jpg";


    return cell;

}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: How is this different to your previous question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33874982/accessing-nsdictionary-within-array ?

Comment: the last one was counting objects within my array, this one is accessing the values (which seam to be further nested). Ive jsut realised that they are named similar. Sorry my bad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can query the top element in json data. It depends upon what is the root element if its an array get it in an array if it is an dictionary get it in an dictionary.

Then depends upon the hierarchy of data what you have to choose.
To get a value from dictionary you have to use ,

[yourDictionary objectForKey:@"keyName"];
It will return you the value. 
You are using an array accessing method on dictionary.You have to use objectForKey. Hope it helps.